# Jquery sortable with scroll when mouse leaves scrollable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery-ui-sortable to sort a list of item horizontally.

However I have a problem, when the list exceeds the with of its container (the UL in the example) and it automatically scrolls to the left/right (as intended).

If the user moves the mouse to fast and it go's outside of the scroll able element (the UL in the example) and then back in again the sorting seems to bug, until the mouse is moved back over an item that is not the last item.
As seen in the example below, until I move my mouse button to the item 17. While i expect the item 1 (the item at the mouse) to be seen at the position between item 18 and 19.

Is there a way to ensure to fix this.

[image: Example of the problem]

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Revvion/cNa5B/

Comment: Clarification: Is the bug that when you go out then back in you are still controlling the position even though the mouse has been released?

Comment: No the mouse is still pressed, and was never released. It occurs when for example I move the mouse to fast and end up outside the UL, I then move the mouse back in. What I want is to continue with the sorting as if the mouse never left the UL.

Comment: I cant recreate your bug so i cant help, sorry.

Comment: I am having the same problem with sortable. +1 because your question is useful. do you have any solution of problem now?